# How can I combine this closed type family with a dependent type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass, dependent-type, type-families, type-level-computation

### My issue

I have the following type family that splits arguments off of a function:

```hs
type family
  SeparateArgs
    ( a :: Type )
      :: ( Type, [Type] )
  where
    SeparateArgs (a -> b) =
      SndCons2 a (SeparateArgs b)
    SeparateArgs a =
      '(a, '[])
```

I also have this typeclass to do the reverse:

```hs
class Refunct args goal newSig | args goal -> newSig where
  refunct :: (HList args -> goal) -> newSig
instance Refunct '[] goal goal where
  refunct makeA = makeA HNil
instance
  ( Refunct tailArgs goal c
  )
    => Refunct (headArg ': tailArgs) goal (headArg -> c)
  where
    refunct hFunct x = refunct $ hFunct . (x :>)
```

Now pretty much every time I use these two, I use them together like the following:

```hs
instance
  ( SeparateArgs a ~ '(goal, args)
  , Refunct goal args a
  , ...
  )
    => ...
```

This is so I can break off the arguments, do some processing to create a function of the type `HList args -> goal` and then turn it back into a regular function.

This works but it is pretty frustrating since I know that `Separate a ~ '(goal, args) => Refunct args goal a`, meaning that only one of these statements is needed.  However the compiler can't tell that so I need to inform it.

It is of course not critical, since my code currently works, but I would like to roll it into one  statement.  Ideally by adding a second functional dependency to `Refunct` like so:

```hs
class
  ( SeparateArgs newSig ~ '(goal, args)
  )
    => Refunct args goal newSig
  | args goal -> newSig
  , newSig -> args goal
  where
    refunct :: (HList args -> goal) -> newSig
```

(Of course this does not work on it's own)

Is there a way to reduce the two (the type family `SeparateArgs` and the type class `Refunct`) into a single constraint?  I am still willing to define additional constructs I would just like to have non-redundant constraints in the result.  I will still need the `refunct` function.

If it is needed here is my implementation of `HList`:

```hs
data HList (a :: [ Type ]) where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  (:>) :: a -> HList b -> HList (a ': b)

hHead :: HList (a ': b) -> a
hHead (a :> _) = a

hTail :: HList (a ': b) -> HList b
hTail (_ :> b) = b
```

### What I have tried

After discussing this elsewhere it was suggested I try:

```hs
type family
  IsAtomic
    ( a :: Type )
      :: Bool
  where
    IsAtomic (a -> b) = 'False
    IsAtomic a = 'True

class
  Refunct args goal newSig
  | args goal -> newSig
  , newSig -> args goal
  where
    refunct :: (HList args -> goal) -> newSig
instance
  ( IsAtomic goal ~ 'True
  )
    =>  Refunct '[] goal goal
  where
  refunct makeA = makeA HNil
instance
  ( Refunct tailArgs goal c
  , IsAtomic (headArg -> c) ~ 'False
  )
    => Refunct (headArg ': tailArgs) goal (headArg -> c)
  where
    refunct hFunct x = refunct $ hFunct . (x :>)
```

Here we add an additional constrain that the first instance only works if `IsAtomic goal ~ 'True` and the second only if `IsAtomic goal ~ 'False` where `IsAtomic` is a type family I've defined which is `'False` on functions and `'True` on everything else.

Here the compiler seems to be unable to confirm that the two instances do not violate the functional dependency.  The exact error is:

```
    Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
      instance (IsAtomic goal ~ 'True) => Refunct '[] goal goal
      instance (Refunct tailArgs goal c, IsAtomic goal ~ 'False) =>
               Refunct (headArg : tailArgs) goal (headArg -> c)
    |
XXX |   ( IsAtomic goal ~ 'True
    |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

(ok it's not exact since I have removed all identifying info).

My intuition here is that it is not aware that `IsAtomic goal ~ 'True` and `IsAtomic goal ~ 'False` cannot both be true at the same time.  This is reasonable since without inspection, we cannot know `IsAtomic` is not `forall a. a` which does satisfy both constraints.

Comment: Side note: The syntax `*` is deprecated. `import Data.Kind` and use `Type` instead.

Comment: @HTNW Thanks!  I usually do, I just wanted minimal dependencies for my example.  I've changed it though since it is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

### What do we want?

In order to solve this we can first break down what it is that we want.

We want the "falling through" of behavior of a closed type family (so that functions and non-functions will match different instances) but we also want to construct data like a type class (so we can get `refunct`).

That is we want a type class with the logic of a close type family.  So in order to do that we can just separate the two parts and implement them separately; the logic as a closed type family and the rest as a type class.

Now to do that we take our type family and we add another paramenter

```hs
class
  Foo
    (bar :: Type)
    (baz :: Type)
    (bax :: Type)
```

becomes

```hs
class
  Foo'
    (flag :: Flag)
    (bar :: Type)
    (baz :: Type)
    (bax :: Type)
```

This parameter will act as a flag to tell us which instance to use.  Since it is of kind `Flag` we need to make that datatype.  It should have a constructor for every instance (we can be a little loose with this in some cases but in general you would want one to one)

```hs
data Flag = Instance1 | Instance2 | Instance3 ...
```

<sup>(In the case of my issue since there are only two instances we use `Bool`)</sup>

Now we build a closed type family which calculates which instance to match.  It should take the relevant arguments from the parameters of `Foo` and produce a `Flag`

```hs
type family
  FooInstance
    (bar :: Type)
    (baz :: Type)
    (bax :: Type)
      :: Flag
  where
    FooInstance ... = Instance1
    FooInstance ... = Instance2
    FooInstance ... = Instance3
    ...
```

<sup>In the case of the question at hand we call this `IsAtomic` since that name is descriptive as to what it does.</sup>

Now we modify our instances to match the correct `Flag`s.  This is pretty simple we just add the instance flag to the declaration:

```
instance
  ( Foo newBar newBaz newBax
  ...
  )
    => Foo' 'Instance3 foo bar baz bax
  where
    ...
```

Importantly we do *not* change recursive calls to `Foo` to calls to `Foo'`. We are about to build `Foo` as a wrapper around `Foo'` that manages our closed type family (`FooInstance` in this case) so we want to call the `Foo` to avoid envoking the same logic every time.

That is built like this:

```hs
class
  Foo
    (bar :: Type)
    (baz :: Type)
    (bax :: Type)
  where
    ...
instance
  ( Foo' (FooInstance bar baz bax) bar baz bax
  )
    => Foo bar baz bax
  where
    ...
```

If we want to be extra safe we can add a line to each `Foo'` instance to check that it is being called correctly:

```
instance
  ( Foo newBar newBaz newBax
  , FooInstance bar baz baz ~ 'Instance3
  ...
  )
    => Foo' 'Instance3 bar baz bax
  where
    ...
```

### My solution

So now we use this strategy on the specific question at hand.
Here is the code in full.  The relevant class is `SeparateArgs`:

```hs
type family
  IsAtomic
    ( a :: Type )
      :: Bool
  where
    IsAtomic (a -> b) = 'False
    IsAtomic a = 'True

class
  SeparateArgs
    (args :: [Type])
    (goal :: Type)
    (newSig :: Type)
  | args goal -> newSig
  , newSig -> args goal
  where
    refunct :: (HList args -> goal) -> newSig

instance
  ( IsAtomic newSig ~ isAtomic -- For (possible? compilation time) speedup
  , SeparateArgs' isAtomic args goal newSig
  )
    => SeparateArgs args goal newSig
  where
    refunct = refunct' @isAtomic

class
  SeparateArgs'
    (isAtomic :: Bool)
    (args :: [Type])
    (goal :: Type)
    (newSig :: Type)
  | args goal -> newSig isAtomic
  , newSig isAtomic -> args goal
  where
    refunct' :: (HList args -> goal) -> newSig
instance
  ( IsAtomic goal ~ 'True -- Only exists to ensure we are not invoking this in an illegal manner
  )
    => SeparateArgs' 'True '[] goal goal
  where
    refunct' makeA = makeA HNil
instance
  ( IsAtomic (headArg -> c) ~ 'False -- Only exists to ensure we are not invoking this in an illegal manner
  , SeparateArgs tailArgs goal c
  )
    => SeparateArgs' 'False (headArg ': tailArgs) goal (headArg -> c)
  where
    refunct' hFunct x = refunct $ hFunct . (x :>)
```